# Sitecore WFFM field order for different languages

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.5

Currently, I have a requirement where I need to change the field order on the form with WFFM for different languages:

Example: **FirstName** field for one language(**en-US**) should appear as the first field on the form whereas the same **FirstName** field should appear second on the same form for another language(**en-GB**).

The current version I'm working with: Sitecore.NET 7.5 (rev. 141003).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple of ways to make this happen -

1. Creating separate forms for different languages - requires no development, but is a maintenance nightmare.
2. Use CSS to reposition the fields - requires development, but easier to maintain. Include the langauge in the form ancestor HTML element's CSS class and add a CSS class to each field in WFFM. In your CSS stylesheed assign the styles accordingly.

Hope this helps!